# Git pulls not updating the local repo

Tags: git, version-control

When we pull the changes from remote repo the changes are not updating in the local repo. Instead it shows as changes to commit in the local repository. I am not pretty sure whether I have explained my issue properly.

Does anyone knows why the local repo is not updating when a pull is done and why it is showing as changes to commit to the local repo.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the git commands and output, e.g., do you see a status message like `Counting objects`?  What does `git branch` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a merge conflict. You need to resolve the conflict and commit the merge to proceed.

Comment: well it doesnt display as a merge conflict and also we resolved the only merge conflict we had in the code.